# How can I connect to bluetooth 4.0 / Bluetooth LE devices from a Mac?

Tags: python, macos, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, python-module

Is it possible to configure a bluetooth LE device as Serial port and use PySerial? Bluetooth 4 devices don't show up under bluetooth system preferences.

In terms of python modules, pybluez can't be installed on mac, and I don't think lightblue has support for bluetooth 4. The only module I found is pyble which I can't get to work.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyble/0.02

The example code gives me the error
"no module named bluetooth" on the code line:

from bluetooth import bluetooth

Answer (score 3):

Most BLE devices don't implement a serial-port-profile as was available under Bluetooth 2.1.

You can get modules that expose a serial port to a micro controller, but on the Bluetooth side this maps to a GATT attribute that is written/read in order to send & receive data from the micro controller.

Other BLE sensor devices such as heart-rate monitors and so on don't have any serial port functionality, they just expose GATT attributes.

The library you linked to seems to be designed around a TI cc2540 module on a PC (It mentions "COM3:" for example) - recent Macs have in-built BLE support, exposed by the IOBluetooth framework but, as you say, lightblue only supports the legacy profiles.